# How to use useFocusEffect hook

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

As the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/use-focus-effect.html,

"Sometimes we want to run side-effects when a screen is focused. A side effect may involve things like adding an event listener, fetching data, updating document title, etc."

I'm trying to use `useFocusEffect` to fetch data everytime that the user go to that page.

on my component I have a function which dispatch an action with redux to fetch the data:

`const fetchData = ()=>{
      dispatch(companyJobsFetch(userDetails.companyId));
 };`

Actually I'm using `useEffect` hook to call `fetchData()`, but I'd like to fetch data everytime that the user go to that page and not only when rendered the first time.

It's not clear from the documentation how to use `useFocusEffect` and I'm not having success on how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The docs show you how to do it. You need to replace `API.subscribe` with your own thing:

```js
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(companyJobsFetch(userDetails.companyId));
  }, [dispatch, companyJobsFetch, userDetails.companyId])
);
```

Comment: I want to refetch every time the screen is re-focused, without any dependency changing however. Just refetch unconditionally. Using `[]` as dependency does not achieve this though as it only fetches on 1st focus (mount), then not. How can we do this?

Comment: @user2078023 Then you just fetch inside the useCallback function above. Where satya164 is doing a dispatch. It should not fetch only on first focus, useFocusEffect runs every time you navigate back to that screen.

Comment: dont we have to remove any subscription. I used useFocusEffect(useCallback(...)) only and it executes on Focus without extra renders. now I am confused if this is enough or am I missing. I am afraid of memory leaks unwanted resource consumption :D

Comment: I don't think what Francesco wants can be achieved by the useFocusEffect hook.

`The useFocusEffect is analogous to React's useEffect hook. The only difference is that it only runs if the screen is currently focused.`

It does not run every time the the screen is focused.

Comment: It runs every time the screen is focused the same way useEffect runs when component mounts.

Answer (score 17):

For version react navigation [4.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/function-after-focusing-screen), you can use addEvent listener

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (navigation.isFocused()) {
      resetReviews(); // replace with your function
    }
  }, [navigation.isFocused()]);
```

OR

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      // The screen is focused
      // Call any action
      _getBusiness({id: business?.id}); // replace with your function
    });
    return () => {
      // clean up event listener
      focusListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

For later version [5.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/), you can use hooks to achieve this

```js
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

// ...

function Profile() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

  return <Text>{isFocused ? 'focused' : 'unfocused'}</Text>;
}
```

Comment: this is simple and easy even we dont need to handle removal of events and all. But this is bit slower as compare to useFocusEffect of @react-navigation/native.